# aws cognito as a login replacement

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, oauth, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have an ASP.net application which currently use JWT tokens for Auth and stores a list of UserNames + Security Roles in a SQL database.

Since we're hosting this application on AWS I'm wondering if I haven't re-invented the wheel. AWS Cognito seems to provide a similar service but I can't quite figure out if Cognito can be used as a replacement for my own implementation.

Long story short is that I'd rather be storing logins and password in a secure AWS store somewhere and using a tried and trusted roles model - rather than rebuild and store logins etc. within my own application.

Can someone tell me if cognito is the correct product for this or is there something better suited for this?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Cognito's [developer authenticated identities feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/) lets you use your own user name, password (store it in AWS or anywhere else) and then obtain AWS credentials. You can setup access permissions in the role and policies based on various factors such as identity pool Id or the identity Id, refer to our [blog](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but this still requires me to store the users credentials in my own store and take responsibility for it's security practices. I'm looking for something that removes that responsibility from me. So I want to keep of record of the user in my DB, but I don't want store the credentials.

Comment: u can store it in DynamoDB or RDS DB, but you have to understand the limitation, especially DynamoDB.  :)